# Django admin get updated model (and updated relative models that are inlines) when "Save" is clicked

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model named `User` and it has some fields, and also some relative models.

It's registered in the admin page and some of its relative models are registered as inlines of it.

Now, I have a function let's call it `update_api(user)` which takes the user as an argument (which is an instance of class `User`) and sends it to an API. Note that this function also uses the relative models of `User`.

I want to call `update_api` when a user is saved in the admin page but I want all his fields and relative inline models to be updated. Moreover I want this function to be called only once per save.

I have tried overriding `User.save()` or `UserAdmin.save_model()` but that lead me nowhere because the related fields were not updated by then.

When user is saved via a view, I call this function manually at the end after doing a `request.user.refresh_from_db()`.

Comment: What's the relationship between user and these other fields?- is it a M2M? because overriding the admin's `save_method()` should generally work. If it's a M2M relation, it **wouldn't** work by default but you could just add a `obj.save_m2m()` then the `update_api` call and it should

Comment: It's one to many. But the related fields are not updated...

Comment: You could try overriding the `save_related()` call in the admin, just put it right after the `save_formset()` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed my problem was putting my code in `UserAdmin.save_formset()` method.

Seems like that's the last method being called from django after user submits the form (atleast that's what I think).

Here is a snippet of the code:

```py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super().save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change)
        user = form.instance
        update_api(user)
```